# Append a Numpy array into a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to append a NumPy array into a PySpark Dataframe.

The result needs to be like this, adding the `var38mc` variable:

```
+----+------+-------------+-------+
|  ID|TARGET|        var38|var38mc|
+----+------+-------------+-------+
| 1.0|   0.0|  117310.9790|   True|
| 3.0|   0.0|  39205.17000|  False|
| 4.0|   0.0|  117310.9790|   True|
+----+------+-------------+-------+
```

Firstly, I calculated an array with the approximation of `117310.979016494` value.

```
array_var38mc = np.isclose(train3.select("var38").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect(), 117310.979016494)
```

The output is an object `numpy.ndarray`, like this `[True, False, True]`

Next, I'm trying to append a `Numpy` array, previously calculated with the data of this same `PySpark.Dataframe`.

```
train4 = train3.withColumn('var38mc',col(df_var38mc))
```

But I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

P.S.: I tried to convert the numpy array into a list and in another PySpark Dataframe without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UDF instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
import numpy as np

func = F.udf(lambda x: bool(np.isclose(x, 117310.979016494)), BooleanType())
train4 = train3.withColumn('var38mc', func('var38'))
```